# Error while installing PyAudio on M1 Macbook even after installing portaudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, anaconda, homebrew

I have installed Xcode and Homebrew. Then I have also installed the portaudio package using Homebrew `brew install portaudio`. After doing that, I have tried to install PyAudio.

I have tried all the following commands:

`pip install pyaudio`

`python3 -m pip install pyaudio`

`conda install -c anaconda pyaudio`

I am currently trying to install PyAudio on my Conda environment. I am using Miniconda on Macbook M1.

Is there any way to solve this, or if not how am I supposed to build the package and place it in my python site-packages??

Kindly Help.

Comment: what error are you getting??

Comment: @BhavyaParikh I got an urllib3 no destination exists error. So when I checked my site-packages located at /../miniconda3/env/DL/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ I found that there was a urllib3 with out 'METADATA' and another urllib3 folder that contained 'METADATA' hence I deleted the folder with out metadata and the installation worked as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing an unwanted urllib3 folder without METADATA inside my python site-packages folder. And then switched the terminal to run on Rosetta2 and It worked.